# How to improve it - digit generator + guess digit from the range

Tags: python

I was trying to create digits range from X to Y - checking if input is a digit. Next guessing level (only 3 attempts): verifying if 'guess' if a digit + if it's from the range. How to simplify it + I am stuck on loop.

```
 from random import randint

# Generates a number from x through y inclusive

while True:
    x1 = raw_input("Please provide x - first digit from the range:  ")
    try: 
        x = int(x1)
        while True:
            y1 = raw_input("Please provide y - last digit from the range:  ")
            try: 
                y = int(y1)
                random_number = randint(x, y)
                guesses_left = 3
                while guesses_left > 0:
                    guess = raw_input("Your guess: ")
                    guesses_left -= 1
                    try:
                        val = int(guess)
                        if val < x:
                            guesses_left += 1
                            print "Another number from range from", x, "to " ,  y
                        if val > y:
                            guesses_left += 1
                            print "Another number from range from", x, "to " ,  y
                        elif val == random_number:
                            print "You win!"
                            break
                    except ValueError:
                        print "That's not digit!"
                        guesses_left += 1
                else:
                    print "You lose."  
                    break  
            except ValueError:
                print "That's not digit!"
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not digit!"
```

Comment: Do you intend to have `random_number = randint(1, 10)` (or to use `x` and `y`)?

Comment: lost this in editing, yes it should be x and y; corrected

Comment: A good way to start might be to wrap your input reader to avoid using a super long try except.
Why not a `def read_input(message):try:return int(raw_input(message)) except: print"That's not a digit"`, this will make the code more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top level, your code has this:

```
while True:
    x1 = raw_input("Please provide x - first digit from the range:  ")
    try: 
        x = int(x1)
        while True:
            y1 = raw_input("Please provide y - last digit from the range:  ")
            try: 
                y = int(y1)
                random_number = randint(1, 10)
            # give three guesses

            except ValueError:
                print "That's not digit!"
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not digit!"
```

There is no way to escape either `while` loop.

Maybe stop after the guesses?

```
while True:
    x1 = raw_input("Please provide x - first digit from the range:  ")
    y1 = raw_input("Please provide y - last digit from the range:  ")
    try: 
        x = int(x1)
        y = int(y1)
        random_number = randint(x, y+1) #<-- note change to number picked
        # give three guesses

        break #<-- way to escape the loop
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not digit!"
```

Comment: why did you add +1 at randint(x, y+1)?

Comment: range(1,3) gives 1, 2. So if you want x to y (inclusive), add one

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with following "Extract Method/Function" refactoring method as described in Martin Fowler "Refactoring Improving the Design of Existing Code" book.

Here is brief of Refactor Function/Method:
https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractFunction.html

Next steps that might be useful are:
Extract (descriptive) Variable
https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html

Then you may think about creating class from this code to encapsulate it in nice way.

If you want to know rules and use it more than once, you may consider reading this book:
https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your program a bit. Still alot of improvements possible. I removed alot of the nesting. You had multiple nested while loops with try except. It makes it hard to read and harder to find mistakes in your code.

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from x through y inclusive

def startGame():
    while True:
        try:
            x1 = raw_input("Please provide x - first digit from the range:  ")
            x = int(x1)
            y1 = raw_input("Please provide y - last digit from the range:  ")
            y = int(y1)
            if x > y:
                x,y=y,x
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not digit!"

    random_number = randint(x, y)
    guesses_left = 3
    while guesses_left > 0:
        guess = raw_input("Your guess: ")
        try:
            val = int(guess)
            if x > val or val > y :
                print ("Another number from range from {} to {}".format(x,y))
            elif val == random_number:
                print "You win!"
                break
            else:
                guesses_left -= 1
                print("You have {} guesses left".format(guesses_left))
        except ValueError as e:
            print "That's not digit!"

    else:
        print "You lose."   

game_loop = True
while game_loop:
    startGame()
    user_inp = raw_input("Do you want to play again y/n ?\n")
    if user_inp not in "yYyesYes":
        game_loop = False
```

Comment: You missed guesses_left -= 1 to decrease numbers of tries. Runs perfect. Thanks

Comment: changed my code a bit to remove a few small mistakes. Should work as intended now.

Comment: if x > y:    
x,y=y,x   - I was already thinking about this condition.

Comment: I am receiving an error on the line: print "Another number from range from", x, "to " ,  y (Exception has occurred: exceptions.IOError) - when  I am choosing numbers below a range